# Change buttons text color while sliding over them

Tags: android, android-layout

I am kinda new to android programming and I am facing a real problem. I am having a layout with some buttons on it, and I am trying to change the text color of buttons by sliding through buttons and after I release my finger I want to go back to the current color for all touched buttons.

I tried to implement a touch listener on every button but I realised that I am totally wrong. So I am thinking I should apply some listener on layout but I am not so sure that a touch listener will help me in some way, because a touch event is much more like an click event and I think what I am trying to do is much more a movement. After I "google it" and tried some things, I got a bit overwhelmed and I am thinking that what I am trying to do is not posibile in the way is it now the layout. I am wondering if it is some way to detect if the finger is sliding over some buttons?

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_braille"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#f8fdf9"
        android:tag="x"
        android:layout_margin="30sp"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#f8fdf9"
        android:tag="x"
        android:layout_margin="30sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_1"
        />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#f8fdf9"
        android:tag="x"
        android:layout_margin="30sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_2"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_4"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#f8fdf9"
        android:tag="x"
        android:layout_margin="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_5"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#f8fdf9"
        android:tag="x"
        android:layout_margin="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_4"
        />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_6"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#f8fdf9"
        android:tag="x"
        android:layout_margin="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_5"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code for touching just one button at a time:

```
 btn_1.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
 btn_2.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
 btn_3.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
 btn_4.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
 btn_5.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
 btn_6.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);

OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // PRESSED
                    actionDown(v.getId());
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // RELEASED
                    actionUp(v.getId());
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    actionHoverEnter(v.getId());
            }
            return false;
        }

private void actionHoverEnter(int id)
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case R.id.btn_1:
                    btn_1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_2:
                    btn_2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_3:
                    btn_3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_4:
                    btn_4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_5:
                    btn_5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_6:
                    btn_6.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void actionUp(int id)
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case R.id.btn_1:
                    btn_1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_2:
                    btn_2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    break;

                case R.id.btn_3:
                    btn_3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_4:
                    btn_4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_5:
                    btn_5.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_6:
                    btn_6.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void actionDown(int id)
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case R.id.btn_1:
                    btn_1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_2:
                    btn_2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_3:
                    btn_3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_4:
                    btn_4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_5:
                    btn_5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_6:
                    btn_6.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `selector` to change the `text_color`.

Comment: Text color works fine as it is now, the thing is I don't know how to fire the events for other buttons while moving my finger over them.